# Restangular response and ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, node.js, sails.js, restangular

I have recently started to learn angularjs using restangular to talk to my restfull API (sails). The problem I have stumbled upon is that the ng-repeat does not update after I change the list in the scope.

Controller:

```
app.controller('UsersCtrl', ['UsersSvc', '$scope', function(UsersSvc, s) {
    UsersSvc.getList().then(function (new_users) {
        s.users = new_users;
    })
    s.destroy = function (user) {
        user.remove().then(function () {
        s.users = _.without(s.users, user);
    });
}
}]);
```

Service:

```
app.factory('UsersSvc', function(Restangular) {
    return Restangular.all('users');
});
```

Template:

```
<div ng-controller="UsersCtrl">
    ...
    <tr ng-repeat"user in users">  
          <td>{{user.firstName}}</td>  
          <td>{{user.lastName}} </td>  
          <td>{{user.emailAddress}}</td>  
          <td>{{user.age}}</td>  
    </tr> 
    ...
</div>
```

When I inspect the scope the array of restangular objects is correctly assigned to the scope of the users controller but the template refuses to update.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I cannot see where you defined `usr.users`. Can you also add this part?

Comment: The usr part was a typo while copying. I am refering to the users variable on the UsersCtrl scope.

Comment: am i right in thinking that `s` refers to `$scope`. Also why not try and console.log the result of the promise, see what you get

Comment: That is correct. The result of the promise returns a correct json array and the users variable changes accordingly. The main problem is that the ng-repeat part of the template does not update itself when the users variable changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AngularJS (and javascript) care about references vs. overwrites. So to be safe I always set my scope variables initially, and then update using `angular.copy()` or `Restangular.copy()` (if it's a Restangular object being set).

Below is how I'd refactor your controller to ensure bindings + digest cycles stay connected.

*(Please note I renamed `s` to the "traditional" `$scope` for easier reading for everyone else)*

```
app.controller('UsersCtrl', ['$scope', 'UsersSvc', 'Restangular', function($scope, UsersSvc, Restangular) {

    // we're expecting a list, so default as array
    $scope.users = [];

    UsersSvc.getList().then(function (new_users) {
        // In normal $resource/ng projects use: angular.copy(src, dst) but
        // Restangular has an issue when using angular.copy():
        // https://github.com/mgonto/restangular/issues/55
        // so use their version of copy():
        Restangular.copy(new_users, $scope.users);
    });

    $scope.destroy = function (user) {
        user.remove().then(function () {
        $scope.users = _.without($scope.users, user);
    });
}
}]);
```

Comment: But now you're injecting the service and Restangular.

Comment: @honeycomb you're right, I switched to http://angular-data.pseudobry.com which is awesome. But I imagine you could include Restangular elsewhere in your angular app, I'd test but I retired Restanguar ;)