# ng-repeat does updated after restangular post request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, restangular

I am using `angularjs 1.5.8` my controller code is as follows

```
angular.module('testmodule')
 .controller('prd',function($scope,Restangular){
    this.items = [];

this.postbody = { "Filter": 700 } ;

Restangular.all('allPrd').post(this.postbody).then(function(data){
   this.items = Restangular.copy(data.tiles);
   console.log(this.items);
})

});
```

And my template is as follows

```
<div ng-controller="prd as prd2">
   <div ng-repeat='item in prd2.items>
     {{prd2.items}}  
</div>
</div>
```

the ng-repeat does not get updated after post request but the console log of this.items is the post request value. How do I proceed thanks in advance.

Note: I tried the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23318127/restangular-response-and-ng-repeat) but it does not still work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside of `then` callback `this` is nothing but global object.

So,`this` has no `items`.

Instead it assign `items` to the global object and it is not reflected in your controller

use `var self = this`

```
.controller('prd',function($scope,Restangular){
var self = this;    
self.items = [];

this.postbody = { "Filter": 700 } ;

Restangular.all('allPrd').post(this.postbody).then(function(data){
   self.items = Restangular.copy(data.tiles);
   console.log(this.items);
})

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use angular `2 way bind`:

```
angular.module('testmodule')
 .controller('prd',function($scope,Restangular){


this.postbody = { "Filter": 700 } ;
$scope.items = {};
Restangular.all('allPrd').post(this.postbody).then(function(data){
   $scope.items = Restangular.copy(data.tiles);
   console.log($scope.items);
})

});
```

and in your HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="prd as prd2">
   <div ng-repeat='item in items'>
     {{item}}  
</div>
</div>
```

the `$scope` is the glue between your `HTML` and `controller`.

Comment: what about `this`.Why `this` is noT glue?

Comment: Yes it uses angular 2-way-bind.

Comment: also the syntax in the HTML needs to match.